# JS Unit testing run multiple times with different parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

Is their any way to have multiple parameters in one test instead of copying and pasting the function again?

Example in NUnit for C#:

```
[TestCase("0", 1)]
[TestCase("1", 1)]
[TestCase("2", 1)]
public void UnitTestName(string input, int expected)
{
    //Arrange

    //Act

    //Assert
}
```

What I want in Js:

```
describe("<Foo />", () => {

    [TestCase("false")]
    [TestCase("true")]
    it("option: enableRemoveControls renders remove controls", (enableRemoveControls) =>  {
        mockFoo.enableRemoveControls = enableRemoveControls;

        //Assert that the option has rendered or not rendered the html
    });
});
```

Comment: Just make a new function and call it, I guess. In general, since you are passing a callback to `it` (and `describe`, etc) you can just make a function that returns a callback `function makeTest(input, expected) { return function() { assert(input === expected)})` then just call it in your tests `it("passes", makeTest(1, 1))` and vary the arguments `it("fails", makeTest("apple", "orange"))`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

An alternative is to use [Jest](https://jestjs.io/). It has this [functionality](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout) built-in:

```
test.each`
  a    | b    | expected
  ${1} | ${1} | ${2}
  ${1} | ${2} | ${3}
  ${2} | ${1} | ${3}
`('returns $expected when $a is added $b', ({a, b, expected}) => {
  expect(a + b).toBe(expected);
});
```

Comment: Tagged templates used in such a smart way! love it

Comment: Thanks for this. Amazing api :)

Comment: This is great! :)

Comment: Looks like `test.each` was added in Jest version 23.X

Comment: is it just me or this doesn't tell you which case failed? (but just says it fails

Answer (score 17):

You can put the `it`-call inside a function and call it with different parameters:

```
describe("<Foo />", () => {

    function run(enableRemoveControls){
        it("option: enableRemoveControls renders remove controls", () =>  {
            mockFoo.enableRemoveControls = enableRemoveControls;

            //Assert that the option has rendered or not rendered the html
        });
    }

    run(false);
    run(true);
});
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative to test.each if you want to keep the test output standard.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) you can combine it with [mocha-testdata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-testdata):

```js
import * as assert from assert;
import { given } from mocha-testdata;

describe('<Foo />', function () {
    given([
        { input: true,  expected: 'some expected value',       description: 'flag enabled' },
        { input: false, expected: 'some other expected value', description: 'flag disabled' },
    ]).
    it('option: enableRemoveControls renders remove controls', function ({ input, expected }) {
        // prepare, act, assert
    });
});
```

In the above sample you'll also notice a `description` field that's not being injected into the test.
This little trick can be used to make the [reported test name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-testdata#data) more meaningful.

Hope this helps!

Jan